# How to connect Eclipse to remote SAP server via rdp?

Tags: eclipse, connection, rdp, sap-gui, abap-adt

Good afternoon, I have an rdp file to connect to a SAP server remotely via SAP Logon.
[image]
[image]
Also on the local machine I have Eclipse which I want to connect to a remote SAP server. Is such a connection possible or does Eclipse need to be on a remote server?
[image]
What data from the rdp file should I enter into the connection settings?

I tried this configuration, but there was no connection.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which Eclipse plugin do you use to connect?

Comment: latest - https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/latest
I don't know if there is such a possibility at all. And what fields should be used to connect. I have not used this functionality before. Is there any tutorial?

Comment: I guess you mean the **ABAP Development Tools** plugin. Tags adjusted.